# Is there a simple way to display a line next to the text using html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to know a simple way to display a line to the right of the text. The line shouldn't be starting from the middle of the text though but instead from the bottom of the text, similar to underlining the text but should exclude the text.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzf6l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```css
hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    border: 0.7px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div>Choose blank <hr></div>
```

Using `<hr>` tag, we can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is very simple and straight forward.

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow and this is my first question, can you please tell me how can i mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `<hr>` tag for horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

The `hr` tag can be used as the bottom line.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: baseline;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<p>SimpleText</p>
<hr> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this...

consider the text you want is 'SAMPLE'

and by your question i understand you need a line after SAMPLE

give a tag to text like p or h1

then do

```
 h1:after{
    content:"";
    give  backgrounf color,,,height,,width,,position compared to h1   etc also give text decoration :underline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be a semantic one, since what the image shows looks like a heading to a section, we could use the `section` element with a `header` element inside it and an `h5` for example. Then add pseudo-element to the `h5` with `:after` and style it any way you want, you should avoid using `hr`, since it is used as a separator between contents.
You can find my approach below:

```css
.header__text {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}

.header__text:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h5 class="header__text">Choose bank</h5>
  </header>
  <main>
    <select name="banks" id="banks">
      <option value="bank name 1">Bank name 1</option>
      <option value="bank name 2">Bank name 2</option>
    </select>
  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <header>
    <h5 class="header__text">Choose city</h5>
  </header>
  <main>
    <select name="cities" id="cities">
      <option value="city name 1">City name 1</option>
      <option value="city name 2">City name 2</option>
    </select>
  </main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is already an answer which provides a way with using CSS grid, a different approach can also be to use a combination of CSS flexbox and a pseudo element.

```css
label.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

label.title span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  /* or use flex shorthand: flex: 1 1 0; */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label.title:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<label class="title">
    <span>Choose bank</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear,But based on your example, you can simply do this.

```css
.description
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Enter image description here <input type="text" class="description" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```